# Owl Carousel theme.default.min.css file does not link with site

Tags: jquery, html, css

The owl carousel works, but the theme.css is not linking up. I have everything exactly where it should be and written right. Any guesses as to why the theme.css is not working/showing up?

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl/owl.carousel.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl/owl.theme.default.min.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<div class="owl-carousel">
     <div class="img">
          <h1>Paul Elliman</h1>
          <h2>Sing a Song For Someone</h2>
          <a href="#">More Info</a>
     </div>
     <div class="img2">
          <h1>Arlene Shechet</h1>
          <h2>The Ceramic Presence in Modern Art</h2>
          <a href="#">More Info</a>
     </div>
     <div class="img3">
           <h1>Jalal Toufic</h1>
           <h2>An Artist Talk</h2>
           <a href="#">More Info</a>
           </div>
</div>

<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you added the style statements inside `<head></head>`

Comment: Yes, both the style statements are inside a head tag